# how can i know if my code is Synthesizable? [Verilog]

Tags: verilog, hdl

In designing a circuit in verilog using top-down method, I can start from the behavior of a circuit followed by defining the details in every module to construct a structural circuit that is synthesizable.
But how can I know if my code is synthesizable?
Are there any guidelines to follow to support synthesis in verilog?

Comment: Yes, there are guidelines and they are specific to which synthesizer you're using.  For actual chip synthesis, I _think_ Synopsys' "Design Compiler" (DC) is the most popular, so you should look at their user guide.  Anyways, whatever target platform or backend process you're going to use, you'll need to read their synthesis rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a 'standard', [IEEE 1364.1](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/mostRecentIssue.jsp?punumber=4140790) but as Martin pointed out each tool supports whatever it wants. I recommend the [Xilinx XST User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx11/xst.pdf) if you need a free resource.

Also, structural verilog typically means you are creating description close to a netlist and the constructs you would use in this case are a small subset of those that are synthesizable.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation that comes with whatever synthesis tool you are going to be using.  This will show you what you can do - sometimes there are very specific ways you have to write code to get the intended results.

Ultimately though, there's nothing to beat experience - run your synthesiser over your code (or small parts of it) at regular intervals and see what the tool produces.